# Trigger window resize in non-active window

Tags: 16.04, window, resize

I would like to trigger a resize command (specifically, something similar to the "begin-resize" keybinding we can configure in `org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings`, or via the GUI as shown in the attached image) in a window, for automation purposes, using a regular command (that can be run from a terminal or script). How can I find the command that correspond to that shortcut?

[image: Keyboard shortcuts on Ubuntu]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xdotool` to do this sort of thing, it has options to search for the window you want to operate on and commands for resizing and much much more.

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/xdotool.1.html

Put your commands in a script then add a keyboard shortcut of your choosing to execute the script.